# Laravel 2-Year Stripe Plan

Tags: laravel, stripe-payments, subscription, payment-processing

I have a Laravel website that utilizes Stripe for subscription payments. I partnered with a local business and through them, I am offering my customers a 2-year subscription plan for the price of 1.

I'd like to charge the customer a one-time fee of $50 (the price of a 1-year subscription). After 2 years (and every re-occurring year after), the customer should be charged $50 a year. How can I do this?

SubscriptionController:

```
$user->charge(5000, $paymentMethod);
$user->newSubscription('plan', 'yearly')->trialDays(730)->create($paymentMethod);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a subscription that has a 2-year coupon applied. When subscribing, charge the customer the price of a single year to cover the first year of the subscription. The normal subscription rules will then kick in after year 2.

Comment: I tried charging the customer while also creating a subscription with a 2-year trial above, but that doesn't work. I don't think I can process 2 charges within the same request.

Comment: Yeah, they’d be two interactions: charging the user, and then creating the subscription. I’d attempt to charge the user first, then create the subscription with coupon if the charge succeeds. If the charge succeeds, the customer will also have a payment method you can use for the subscription.

Comment: I actually could process 2 interactions with the user's payment method in the same request. I just had to place `$user->charge(5000, $paymentMethod);` after the `newSubscription()` method. After I made the necessary changes, this worked using a 2-year coupon. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`trial_end`](https://stripe.com/docs/api/subscriptions/update#update_subscription-trial_end) to set an explicit timestamp up to two years from the billing anchor/start date.

Using Laravel Cashier, I believe you would do this with `trialUntil($timestamp)`.

Comment: Can you be more specific? Do you get an error? The `trial_end` works that way, but I can't really say what Laravel supports or doesn't.